# Zend action to run php script without reloading

Tags: php, zend-framework

Isit possible to have a zend view which returns nothing?

I have the following, which is probably wrong:

```
     $oContextSwitch->addContext("print",array("suffix" => "something"));
```

I call the view like so something.com/stuff/view/format/print

I don't actually know what suffix is doing, but I can have the context with out it. I have read the docs I just really don't understand them!

Anyway this view is called from some highcharts javascript which is already embedded on a page, there is some svg data posted to the view as part of the link.

Now I want this view to do some stuff, mainly save and convert the svg data. BUT I want it to do this without reloading the page, can a view return nothing? and can the page which called the view still be available?

Thanks

Comment: 1) What's the point of a view that doesn't return anything?  How would you know if the action it fronts for succeeded or not?  2) PHP on a web server is a request/response architecture.  The only way to invoke a script more than once is to reload it (Unless you're talking AJAX, where the browser basically automatically reloads a resource under javascript control).

Comment: Basically I want the view to open a new tab and display a jpg file, but I want the original tab with the highcharts chart on to stay as it is without redirecting

Comment: PHP has no concept of browser tabs.  How can it know if the connecting browser supports tabs?  How does it know that the connecting client is even a browser?

Comment: well I guess that bit would be javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
```

that will disable your layout and in your view file just leave it empty, zend will return nothing. However i think that's only going to solve part of your delima. Your using Highcharts (great script btw) so your also using jquery. Your going to want to use jquery to load the new tab your wanting dynamically. that new tab is going to need content right? well are you sure that the ajax call you just made to the zend script that's supposed to return nothing isn't the ideal page to return what you want in that new tab?

Comment: This is exactly what I did in the end. Modified the chart to open a new tab and redirect it to the view :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a view which outputs nothing.

But before using this view you must change to a layout which is also empty.

This way you can have a view with no output.

to change the layout used use this script.

```
//from controller
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('/path/to/your/layout_script');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this but I think I've been a bit vague. I've figure that I need to do an ajax call to the view script from highcharts. Thanks for your input though!